# calling parent activity method from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am little confuse which is the best way to call Parent Activity method as I can easily call parent Activity method from fragment using

```
1. ((Activity)getActivity()).getMethod()
```

and other way I have to create interface and doing onAttach stuffs etc. which also explained in android developer website [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)

now my question is which is the best way and why?

Comment: I would normally prefer to use the interface way, because a fragment may not be used only in the MainActivity. If two different activities both use the same fragment, the interface way would be better. However if a fragment is certainly to be used in one activity, the cast way requires much less code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create an interface. The reason is to make the fragment reusable i.e. It can be called by any activity of your application, who has implemented your fragment's interface.